# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embeds[0].description: This field is required

Tags: typescript, discord

I'm trying to make a bot command that DMs a user. I followed a bunch of guides cause I'm totally new to coding. However when I run this it does work, but right after it crashes and gives me the error: "DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embeds[0].description: This field is required" and then some more.

```
    import { Channel, ClientUser, MessageManager, User } from "discord.js";
    import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";
    
    export default {
        category: 'Replies',
        description: 'bot dm',
    
        permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],
  
        testOnly: true,
    
        callback: async ({message, interaction, channel, args, client}) => {
           
            if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("i need a user to dm!")
    
            const user = message.mentions.members?.first() || message.guild?.members.cache.get(args[0])
            if(!user) return message.channel.send("couldn't find user")
    
            const content = args.slice(1).join(" ")
            if(!content) return message.channel.send("need something to say")
    
            try {
    
                await user.send(content)
    
                return message.channel.send("dmed")
    
            } catch {
    
                return message.channel.send("cant dm")
    
            }
        }
    } as ICommand
```

I've tried a few things, all that I can do with my limited knowledge and googling to figure this out like changing `await user.send(content)` to `await user.send(`${content}`)` but it didn't work obviously. Please help. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found your question while searching how to fix my own. From what I can tell, something in your code appears to be trying to use message embedding rather than simply dm'ing a user. It is not clear from the snippet where this might be happening.

If you are following a guide I suggest finding a different one as the above seems overly complex and is causing you issues beyond the scope of your application.

If you are using message embedding, then as per the error it requires a 'description' property. Fixing my embed was as simple as that.

```
createEmbed() {
    this.CharEmbed = {
        'title': 'The title of my embed!',
        'color': `${this.currentColor}`,
        'description': "I needed this bit.",
        'footer': {
            'text': `${this.footer}`
        },
        'fields': [...]
     }
}
```

It's slightly older, though not deprecated, but this is the guide that I used to get me started with bot development: https://www.howtogeek.com/364225/how-to-make-your-own-discord-bot/

The tutorial he provides is easily extended to achieve what you're attempting.